# If $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ be the two sides of a $||$gm ..

Tags: analytic-geometry

If $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ be the two sides of a parallelogram and $px+qy=1$ is its one diagonal, prove that the other diagonal is $y(bp-hq)=x(aq-hp)$.

My Approach.

Here, $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ represents aa pair of lines passing through the origin. 
$$ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$$
Multiplying both sides by $a$
$$a^2x^2+2ahxy+aby^2=0$$
$$a^2x^2+2ahxy+h^2y^2-h^2y^2+aby^2=0$$
$$(ax)^2+2.ax.hy+(hy)^2-(h^2-ab)y^2=0$$
$$(ax+hy)^2-(\sqrt {h^2-ab} y)^2=0$$
Then,
$$ax=\left(h \pm \sqrt {h^2-ab}\right)y$$

I got stuck at here. Please help me to continue.

Answer (score 1):

This is the straightforward (and hence the longest) method of finding the required solution.

Continuing from your work, we get the two lines $L_1: y = m_1x$ and $L_2: y = m_2x$; where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are functions of a, h, and b.

One corner of the //gm is O(0, 0).

Since the given diagonal cuts $L_1$ and $L_2$ at A and B respectively, the co-ordinates of them can then be found. From those, obtain the co-ordinates of M, the midpoint of AB.

OA is the other diagonal.

There must be some other simpler ways. One probably involves the manipulation of sum and product of roots.