# If $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ be the $\dots$

Tags: analytic-geometry

If $ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 =0$ be the two sides of a parallelogram and $px + qy = 1$ be its one diagonal then prove that the equation of the other diagonal is $y(bp-hq)=x(aq-hp)$.

> **While searching for the answers, I got this answer on 'Yahoo answers' but I did not understand anything over here. Please anyone make me clear about it.**

Let the parallelogram be $OPMQ$ ($PQ$ given diagonal)
then $$ax²+2hxy+by²+λ(px+qy−1)=0$$ is a conic
through $P$ and $Q$. For this to be 2nd pair of sides of parallelogram
it must be of form $$a(x−X)²+2h(x−X)(y−Y)+b
(y−Y)²=0$$
( that is the same as given pair of sides but
translated to $M(X,Y)$ as origin )
Quadratic terms are of course identical.
Comparing linear terms gives $$−2aX
−2hY=λp, −2bY−2hX=λq.$$
Divide to eliminate $λ$ and get $$Y/X = (aq
−hp)/(bp−hq).$$
2nd diagonal through $O$ is $y/x=Y/X$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ be the two sides of a $||$gm ..](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927927/if-ax22hxyby2-0-be-the-two-sides-of-a-gm)

Comment: Actually I want the explanation of the answer I gave.

Comment: Having seen your previous answer (the reference given by @Rohan), let me say that you **must** recall when asking a very related question the reference to the initial question.

Comment: Little explanation of the answer that has been given to you on Yahoo. It involves the concept of _pencil of conics_. If you have two conics $C_0$ and $C_{\infty}$ with equations $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$, $f(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y)=0$ is the equation of a conic $C_{\lambda}$ (passing through the common points of $C_0$ and $C_{\infty}$). The set of all these conics is called a "pencil of conics". Pencils have many other properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Other than this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927927/if-ax22hxyby2-0-be-the-two-sides-of-a-gm)**:

---

Let $y = m_1x$ and $y=m_2x$ be the two lines represented by $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ so that $$m_1+m_2 = -\frac{2h}{b} \text{  and   } m_1m_2=\frac{a}{b}...(1)$$ Let $OA$ and $OC$ represent these lines and let the line $px+qy=1$ meets $OA$ and $OC$ at $A$ and $C$. After completing te parallelogram, we have to find the equation of the diagonal $OB$. Let the two diagonals intersect at $M(x_1, y_1)$.

The line $px+qy=1$ meets $y=m_1x$ at $A(\frac{1}{p+qm_1}, \frac{m_1}{p+qm_1})$ and $y=m_2x$ at $C(\frac{1}{p+qm_2}, \frac{m_2}{p+qm_2})$. Now the coordinates of the midpoint of $A$ and $C$ are given by $$M(x_1, y_1) = M(\frac{2p+q(m_1m_2)}{2(p+qm_1)(p+qm_2)}, \frac{p(m_1+m_2)+2qm_1m_2}{2(p+qm_1)(p+qm_2)})...(2)$$ Equation of the other diagonal $OB$ is thus, $$y-0 = \frac{y_1-0}{x_1-0}(x-0) \Rightarrow \frac{y}{x} = \frac{y_1}{x_1}$$ Substituting the coordinates from $(2)$ gives us the required answer.